# VSTS URL load test results - understanding requests per second

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

I have a simple URL-based load test defined in VSTS (Visual Studio Online) that goes through 4 pages of the site I'm testing. I'm trying to understand how the tests are repeated because the Throughput chart is showing that it's making around 10,000 requests per second (blue line), regardless of the number of virtual users (orange line):

[image: Throughput chart of my load test]

I was expecting requests/second to grow linearly in step with the number of users?

Comment: Provide the detail report of load test.